Google App Engine showing only index.php file
I deployed my PHP application for the first time on Google App Engine via Google Cloud SDK CLI. it contains 4 php files. All the php files are in the same folder.
Here is my issue. When I run my application, it only shows content of index.php file, irrespective of the PHP file that I call from the browser. How can I debug this?
Docs Source
Here is my app.yaml file
 runtime: php81
    handlers:
    # Serve php scripts.
    - url: /(.+\.php)$
      script: \1
  


Please update your question so that it represents a minimal repro of your issue, the exact steps that you took to deploy the app and how you're testing the result with any errors. Please correct the app.yaml so that it is valid (handlers: should not be indented).

Your title says "Google cloud storage" but I think this should be "Google App Engine"

You're using php8 and GAE has a different way of handling it from php 5 (the document you referred to).
According to the documentation, you should either deploy a front controller to handle the routing or you code your index.php file to do that. The doc provided the following sample for using index.php
switch (@parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['path']) {
    case '/':
        require 'homepage.php';
        break;
    case '/contact.php':
        require 'contact.php';
        break;
    default:
        http_response_code(404);
        exit('Not Found');
}

